# How to reuse images already loaded to memory in a CNN Keras?

Tags: image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

## Background

I am building a neural network with image and other numerical data as input. I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend.
The network has 2 input parts:
1) images, followed by a few conv layers
2) numerical data, followed by dense layers

The number of unique images is small, but the training data is large.
Most images appear multiple times in input data.
(Unique image count: around 2,000
training data: 500,000 rows)

Example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|  
|      Image_id       | Other data cols  |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |         1        |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |         2        |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |         3        |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|          2          |         4        |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|          2          |         5        |  
|---------------------|------------------|
```

## My Question:

Is there any way to reuse the image data already in memory during training instead of creating a huge numpy array with all the corresponding image data?

## Usual approach would be something like:

```
scaled pixel values for image 1 - other data 1  
scaled pixel values for image 1 - other data 2  
scaled pixel values for image 1 - other data 3  
...  
scaled pixel values for image 1 - other data 1000
```

As you can see, this approach would result in a numpy array with repeating image data taking up too much memory.

Surprisingly hard to find similar cases on the net. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: are you repeating same image in a single input? if so, why?

Comment: I'm using the same image in various input rows.
Imagine a model trying to predict what type of user will like an Instagram image. (My actual use case if different.)

Comment: 25 yrs old, female, input_image_1 -> LIKE    |

26 yrs old, female, input_image_1 -> LIKE    |

42 yrs old, male, input_image_1 -> DID NOT LIKE


I have many rows of input data, but far less actual images. I'd like to look up images by id when training.

Comment: you can write a custom DataLoader where you need to only load the non-repeating images once and then on each batch assign the corresponding image according to its ID

Comment: I see!! I'm an idiot, I totally missed it. 

Something like this:   
model.fit_generator(   generator=data_generator_class_made_by_me.my_function(params),
 ...)

Comment: @xashru Could you write an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: done, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a custom Data Geberator class in Keras. Have look in the [here](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) to understand how to do it. What you will need to modify here

1. Load your images once and save in a `ID(string)-data(numpy array)` dictionary.
2. Pass this dictionary (`data_dict`) in `__init__`
3. In `__data_generation` use `X[i,] = data_dict[ID]`